# Combine Albums At iTunes

Tags: windows-xp, itunes

I'm using Windows XP Home that came with my Eee PC 904HD, and using iTunes on it to sync all that I have on my iPod Touch 3g, but there are two albums on my organizer that are split(don't know why), I've checked and all their tags are the same, but I want to know how I can combine them. As you can see they are the same album, but only with the second music separated.

Here is the screenshot:
[image: iTunes is mad?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully - one track has no umalut (the little sideways : on top of the i) and as such is alone. fixing that should sort it out

Answer (score 0):

A space at the end of the album name could cause this.

Comment: I've checked both, and nothing was found **:(**

Answer (score 0):

A solution (if you can't discover why they are separate tracks) is to tell iTunes all the tracks are part of a compilation.

To do this highlight all the tracks, right click > Get Info > Options Tab.  Check 'part of a compilation' and select yes from the dropdown.

Hit OK and this will group all the tracks in iTunes as a single album.